# add Validator to existing FormItem Validators in smartgwt

Tags: forms, validation, smartgwt

in a smartgwt DynamicForm, how can I add a validator to an existing set of validators within a FormItem ?

The only method I found in the official api is "setValidator(Validator)", but this seems to overwrite all the existing ones.

I would prefer a java approach to this (i.e. using smartgwt api), but in the end, if no solutions are available, at least a "js" native method would do the job.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you don't want to by trying to dynamically add a validator at all.

First, read the Data Binding section of the QuickStart Guide, which shows how you can add screen-specific validators to a form while still inheriting validators declared in the DataSource.

Second, if you're trying to dynamically change the list of validators because some data that validation depends on is changing, take a look at the CustomValidator instead.

If you have some reason to add a validator dynamically that isn't handled by these approaches, try explaining it in detail.

Finally, you can continue with your current approach (not recommended) if you just refactor such that you can provide all the appropriate validators to the FormItems in a single setValidators() call.

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve, I have built a class facilities for building and assigning common validators on FormItem. Such validator include currency check, very specific date format ecc. In few forms I am in need of adding more specific validators, in addition to the common one. But with setValidaotrs(..), the previous one got removed.

Comment: Sounds like you did not read the QuickStart Guide chapter on Data Binding that I referred you to.  You can add as many additional validators as you like: provide them in FormItems for a specific DynamicForm, and they are automatically combined with DataSource validators.  Again, all covered in the QuickStart Guide.

Comment: uhm...obviously I didn't read the doc between 16:16 and 9:32, but I have read later before your latest comment, but I couldn't find a way of adding validators to a FormItem that already has an existing set of validators. I am quite new to smartgwt, can you point out the page where this is mentioned ? Just a note, all the application is built on pure java code, with no use of xml.

Comment: Again, it's in the Data Binding chapter.  You can define a DataSource (in Java or XML) that has validators, then a specific form can declare additional validators.  Just to make sure you can't miss it, here's a running sample: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_form_databinding

Comment: Sorry, forgive my ignorance, I know it's in the DataBinding chapter. Probably my lack of knowledge of smartgwt don't make me understand clear. The original question is that I have factory which build and return the most common form fields with a bunch of validators already set, then in my form I can do form.setItems(FormUtil.getCustomerAccountItem(),..ecc), but it happens that few forms need to add new validators. The link you gave is showing only how to add validators at creation time and this is a well understood mechanism. And finally, what a DataSource has to do with my question ?

Comment: Leonardo, if the QuickStart Guide doesn't help you to understand, I don't think I can do better.  Suffice it to say that if you haven't been using DataSources, you're missing out on the most power features of SmartGWT, and you've probably been creating a bunch of code you don't need, and should start over with an architecture where you are using DataSources.  If you continue with your current approach (not recommended) just refactor such that you can provide all the appropriate validators to the FormItems in a single setValidators() call.

Comment: uhm, ok it's clear, the problem is that I was trying to figure out how the datasource issue could help me with the existing code. Instead, this latest is really the answer I needed, there's no way of doing that with the current code, the only option is a refactoring wich point to a single setValidators(...). If you could rearrange your answer I can mark it as solved.

Comment: Rearranged as requested.  As far as DataSources, if it wasn't clear before, switching to DataSources would not be an incremental change to your current code.  However the reason to do is that you would probably be able to delete most of your current code, because you are probably duplicating functionality better provided by DataSources.